# Why is my main content area text not updating? Did I get the reference wrong?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am not a flash developer, but I am debugging an issue where the copy/text is not rightly assigned.

In the `.as` file, the headings and subheadings are assigned and work:

```
195                         body.heading.htmlText = heading;
196                         body.sectionheading.htmlText = nav_name;
197                         body.subheading.htmlText = subheading;
198                         body.subheading.htmlText = 'testtt';
```

However, the main body copy does not:

```
180                         body.textholder.myText.htmlText = 'mederTest';
```

Is there some way I could find out all text areas ( anything that has an assignable `htmlText` ) programmatically? In Flash itself I can't seem to select the heading/subheading objects themselves, as they dont appear to be in the canvas? They appear hidden.

**Edit: I'm on my 24th swf of debugging. I have finally found the actual text that needs to be updated.**

```
428                 var bodyClip:MovieClip = eval("bodyparts.bodycontent_"+tmpclipname.id+"_0");
429                 ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , bodyClip )
430                 for ( var p in bodyClip ) {
431                     ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , p )
432                     ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , bodyClip[p] )
433                     ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , bodyClip[p] )
434                     for ( var thing in bodyClip[p] ) {
435                         if ( thing === 'htmlText' ) {
436                             ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , 'OMG' );
437                             ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , bodyClip[p][thing] )
438                         }
439                         
440                         if ( thing === 'myText' ) {
441                             ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , 'SUPEROMG' );
442                             ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , bodyClip[p][thing]['htmlText'] )
443                         }
444                         ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , thing )
445                     }
446                 }
```

It drills down and when bodyClip has an instance with a 'myText' property, THATS the thing I want to update.

Why doesn't this line update it?

```
body.textholder.myText.htmlText = 'mederTest';
```

Programmatically speaking, it could only be because I'm possibly referencing the wrong object/instance, no? The `.as` file does not contain a reference to `body`.

I can only assume it was define in the first `.as` file or its a global object. Can anyone lend me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

You can walk the display list, looking for objects of type TextField:

```
function findTextFields(container:DisplayObjectContainer):Array
{
    var result:Array = [];

    // Examine each child of the container
    for(var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var obj:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);

        // If the child is a TextField, add it to the result array
        if(obj is TextField)
            result.push(obj);

        // If the child is a DisplayObjectContainer, recurse on it
        var c:DisplayObjectContainer = obj as DisplayObjectContainer;
        if(c !== null)
            result.concat(findTextFields(c));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: By the way, this is Actionscript 2 I believe. I have updated my question because I found what I need to update in the previous `.as`, except I need to update it from the second `.as`. Mind helping me?

Comment: Ah, you're right, that is AS2. Sorry, I really don't know anything about AS2, and it looks like your problem is pretty specific to it (the code you posted in your edit wouldn't really make sense in AS3). Hopefully there are some AS2 gurus around who can help.

Answer (score 0):

As well as TextFields, there's also StaticText which is the object that gets exported if we put a normal TextField down in Flash and it's not dynamic.

It's possible that the textfield you're looking for is this type, in which case, you won't be able to set the text.

For a truly hack-tastic response though, if you can't re-edit this TextField and make it dynamic, then one solution would be to dynamically create a new TextField. Copy the width, height, font, colour etc of the old one. Either set the background property to true, or set the old TextField's visible property to false. Now add your new TextField as a child of the parent of the old TextField, just above it. Edit the text as you please :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to amend the text from within your if statement when you discover it? Or somewhere else?

```
if ( thing === 'myText' ) {
  bodyClip[p][thing]['htmlText'] = "mederTest"
}
```

.. because its possible the TextField doesn't exist when you are trying to alter it. If the playhead is not on a frame which contains the TextField, the TextField doesn't exist.

Another suggestion is to change the _alpha of the Textfield to make sure you are working on the correct Textfield?